# In Scala, can you make an anonymous function have a default argument?

Tags: scala, anonymous-function

This works:

```
scala>  def test(name: String = "joe"): Boolean = true 
test: (name: String)Boolean
```

I expected this to work in the same way:

```
scala>  val test: String => Boolean = { (name: String = "joe") => true }

console>:1: error: ')' expected but '=' found.
```

Comment: I don't seem to find the relative doc but it seems it's impossible... May I ask why you would define an anonymous function with a default parameter?

Comment: I had a function with a default parameter, I wanted to transform that into a Memoized function, which involves passing my function as an argument to a Memoize method.

I can do what I want by just naming my method and giving the memoized version a different name, but I was still curious about this.

Comment: Well, in that case you could name the non memoized function and simply assign the memoized function to a variable when you need it, like: def A(): Unit {}; val b = memoize(A) or something like that...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The boring, correct answer is no, you can't, but actually you kind of can, with the experimental [single abstract method (SAM) synthesis](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3037) in 2.11.

First you need to define your own SAM type with the default value for the `apply` method's parameter:

```
trait Func {
  def apply(name: String = "joe"): Boolean
}
```

Now you can use the function literal notation to define a `Func` (note that you'll need to have started the REPL with `-Xexperimental` for this step to work):

```
val f: Func = { (name: String) => name == "joe" }
```

Or just:

```
val f: Func = _ == "joe"
```

And then the usual stuff:

```
scala> f("joe")
res0: Boolean = true

scala> f("eoj")
res1: Boolean = false
```

And the punchline:

```
scala> f()
res2: Boolean = true
```

It's not exactly the syntax you're asking for, and there are no promises that this will ever leave experimental status, and even if it does, default arguments may not be supported—but I still think it's pretty neat that it works now.

Answer (score 9):

To expand on "The boring, correct answer is no" in Travis Brown's answer:

Functions (i.e. objects of `FunctionN[...]` type) can't have default arguments in Scala, only methods can. Since anonymous function expressions produce functions (and not methods), they can't have default arguments.

Comment: +1, could have been a little more explicit about this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is bit dirty solution I think, using currying

```
def testDef(nameDef: String)(name2: String): Boolean = { 
  val name3 = if ( name2 != "") name2 else nameDef 
   //use name3 for your logic 
    true 
  }
```

`//> testDef: (name: String)(name2: String)Boolean`

Curry the testDef method to hold default value as shown below.

```
var test = test("joe")_   //> test  : String => Boolean=function1

test("fun") //"fun" will be used as name3  
test("") //  "joe" will be used as name3
```

Comment: Passing a specific argument (the empty string, in this case) isn't really at all like not passing an argument.

Comment: With Dotty, using literal types, Union types, and symbols, this could easily be done as `default|String so the 'specific argument' is now in the type signature. No need to fuss about nulls, no need to fuss about magic default in-band values.