# Keeping named and default parameters when assigning a function

Tags: scala, named-parameters, default-parameters

When assigning a function using an unapplied method, it appears that named and default parameters are lost. Is there any way to avoid this?

```
def foo(namedParam: String = "defaultValue") = namedParam*2
// scala> foo()
// res8: String = defaultValuedefaultValue

def bar = foo _
// scala> bar()
// <console>:28: error: not enough arguments for method 
//               apply: (v1: String)String in trait Function1. 
//               Unspecified value parameter v1.
```

The reason I want to do this is to bundle my imports in a single file, i.e.

**myproject/imports.scala**

```
object imports {
  def externalAPIFunction = myproject.somepackage.internalFunction _
}
```

**scala shell**

```
import myproject.imports._

externalAPIFunction() // no named or default arguments :(
```

Any way to do this or do I have to put my default arguments in the external function definition?

Comment: [Not entirely unrelated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25235029/334519).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions (i.e. values of type `Function<N>[...]`) simply can't have default or implicit parameters in Scala, only methods can. And `method _` returns a function: that's what it's for. So yes, to achieve your purpose you'd need to write

```
object imports {
  def externalAPIFunction(namedParam: String = "defaultValue") = 
    myproject.somepackage.internalFunction(namedParam)
}
```

You can avoid duplication using

```
object imports {
  val x = myproject.somepackage
}

// elsewhere
import myproject.imports._

x.internalAPIFunction()

// or
import myproject.imports.x._

internalAPIFunction()
```

which may or may not be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: I see, thanks! I was hoping to avoid having to use more than one import statement, and also to include implicit methods, I may have to restructure where the functions are defined...

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use currying.

```
def foo()(namedParam: String = "defaultValue") = namedParam * 2
                                                  //> foo: ()(namedParam: String)String
  // scala> foo()
  // res8: String = defaultValuedefaultValue

  def bar() = foo() _                             //> bar: ()String => String
  bar()                                           //> res0: String => String = <function1>
```

Comment: That returns a function, but if you try to invoke that function, `bar()()` you still get the same error...