# Passing DEFAULTS args in function scala

Tags: scala, function

[image]

I'm trying to pass a default args in a function like we can do in method ..But im getting an error. Is it possible to pass a default args / named args to a function like method?
Is it possible to pass named arguments in function while calling it ?

Comment: can you post your sample code? what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: Please post the sample code.

Comment: Plzz dont. Downvote and  forgot to add = after f

Comment: Please, post your code. And I mean your code, not a photograph of your code. This is a programming site, not a photography site; we want to copy&paste&debug your code, not critique its use of color and perspective.

Comment: Sorry sir don't get me wrong but I had written a code , but some one asked me to send entire code so I took snippet and I'm asking my question through phone so I uploaded snippet .u r great coder I admire it but don't spread negativity but such arguing things instead of answering the question .Once again m sorry Sir!!

Comment: I would *love* to answer the question, but unfortunately, I am not able to copy your code into my editor to test it.

Answer (score 1):

This only works for methods (which are defined with `def`).

```scala
def func(i: Int = 2) = i
```

However, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25235029/4357046) is somewhat of a "hack" to do it regardless.

Comment: Wow, that Travis Brown is one scary dude.

Answer (score 1):

```
var f(i:Int=2,j:Int) => i + j
```

This does not work. If you want to define a lambda, try this

```
val f = (i:Int,j:Int) => i + j
```

This is the correct approach. Also you cannot assign default values in lambda. You need to define methods with def keyword. Try this:

```
def f(i:Int, j:Int=2) = i + j
```

Parameter with default value should be the last parameter because scala compiler will scan values from left-right. It'll only use default values if there are missing ones. In above code `f(1)` will produce 3 because `j` will use 2 as default value. So use the compulsory arguments in the left side and the ones with default values on right. Hope this helps

Explained here: [In Scala, can you make an anonymous function have a default argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234682/in-scala-can-you-make-an-anonymous-function-have-a-default-argument)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a curried function here

```
def sum1(a:Int=2)(b:Int) = a+b

sum1(33)
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

[Named arguments](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/named-arguments.html) work with function definitions. Parameters with [defaults](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/default-parameter-values.html) don't need to be given:

```scala
class my
{
    def f(i:Int = 2, j: Int) = i + j
}

var my = new my()

my.f(j = 1)        // i = 2, j = 1
my.f(i = 3, j = 1) // i = 3, j = 1
my.f(3, 1)         // i = 3, j = 1
```